# scandir match function arguments

Tags: c, function-prototypes, scandir

I am using scandir to match certain files from a dir. The match function takes `const struct dirent *dp` argument.

But I also need to pass another argument with it. When I try to do that, compiles gives me a warning (not error) that my match function is of incompatible pointer type.

Is it not allowed to pass another argument to match function? If it's not, I might have to make that particular variable global which I do not want to do.

code snippet:

```
/* below I am adding new argument - char *str */
match_function (const struct dirent *dp, char *str) {
}

function() {
count = scandir(PATH, &namelist, match_function, alphasort);
}
```

warning:

```
warning: passing argument 3 of 'scandir' from incompatible pointer type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach, which may be preferable to using global variables or thread-specific data, is just to write your own replacement for `scandir` and have it take an extra `void *` argument which it would pass to the match function. Considering that `scandir` is easily implemented in less than 50 lines of code, this is perfectly reasonable.

Here is a possible implementation of `scandir`:

http://git.etalabs.net/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=musl;a=blob;f=src/dirent/scandir.c

Comment: Thanks R.. On a side-note, why did compiler just throw warning and not an error?

Comment: We have gcc to thank for all the horribly bad code full of undefined behavior out there. :-( If it gave actual errors when it encountered invalid code or constructs that necessarily invoke UB, people would be forced to fix it...

Comment: Can't agree anymore. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The only portable and thread/library-safe way to do what you want is with POSIX thread-specific data.

```
static pthread_key_t key;
static pthread_once_t init = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
static void initfunc()
{
    int r = pthread_key_create(&key);
    assert(r==0);
}

match_function (const struct dirent *dp)
{
    char *str = pthread_getspecific(key);
    /* ... */
}

function() {
    pthread_once(&init, initfunc);
    pthread_setspecific(key, str);
    count = scandir(PATH, &namelist, match_function, alphasort);
}
```

If you don't care about thread-safety you can just use a global variable for `str` and make it a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

To explicitly answer your question

> Is it not allowed to pass another argument to match function?

No. The author of `scandir()` specified what type of `match` function it expects; as the user of `scandir()` you must follow that specification, or write your own `scandir()`-equivalent that does things the way you want as suggested by [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r).

Answer (score 0):

Think about it:  how would you pass the additional parameter to it?  What you're probably looking for is a closure, which isn't supported by the C standard yet although `gcc` apparently has the ability to do it via [nested functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions).